# External memory merge sort

Tags: memory, sorting, merge, mergesort

Can anyone point me to a good reference on External Memory Mergesort?  I've read the wiki page but am having trouble understanding it exactly.  An animation might help but I can't seem to find one.

Basically, I know that you have a certain number of blocks on disk, and you can fit a certain number of blocks in memory.  Lets say you have 32 blocks on disk and 4 blocks in memory.  In the first pass you read 4 blocks into memory at a time, sort them in memory, and write them back out do disk.  So at this point you have 8 sorted runs of 4 blocks.  How does the merging work?  Since I have 4 blocks in memory (assume I have one more for output) I think I should be able to merge 4 of those 8 runs at a time, and then merge the next 4 runs.  And then in the last pass I want to merge the whole thing.  But don't you have to read each block from disk each time?  So how does this not become a n^2 solution?

Comment: No it's not homework, I'm studying some old notes and can't get it to click anymore

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I get it now.  When you merge you still have to read all of the blocks on disk (let's call that B) but you don't have to read them B times.  You only read them B log B times.

Comment: When you merge the 4 input blocks and put the result in the last block, doesn't the last block need to be 4 times the size of input blocks to hold the result ?